# Konvajs how to dragging a Transformer programatically

Tags: html5-canvas, konvajs, konva

I want my transformer dragging the bottom-right down and up automatically to a certain point when the page is loaded without user interaction.
But I can't find a way to do that.

Here my transformer

```js
  const tr = new Konva.Transformer({
    keepRatio: true,
    borderStrokeWidth: 3,
    borderStroke: "blue",
    enabledAnchors: ['top-left', 'top-right', 'bottom-left', 'bottom-right']
  });
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @VanquishedWombat I'm creating an internal site for worker with low technical skill. So I need to show the user that the image is resizeable. I have the option to show a video instead to user, but I want to try this approach first.

Comment: Did you see my new answer?

Answer (score 0):

Transformer size matches the size of the shapes within it. In your use case of showing that the height of an image can be changed, set the height of the image and call transformer.forceUpdate() to ensure the transformer sees the change.

See https://konvajs.org/docs/select_and_transform/Force_Update.html